# Почему не работает hover для элементов внутри flex?

Tags: html, css, sass

Не могу понять почему не работает событие hover по элементам внутри flex контейнера

**HTML:**

```
<div class="way1"></div>
<div class="bottom_ways">
  <div class="way2"></div>
  <div class="way3"></div>
</div>

<div class="center"></div>
<div class="arrow">Color</div>
```

**SCSS/SASS:**

```
body
  margin: 0
  overflow: hidden
.way1, .way2, .way3
  text-align: center
  height: 50vh
  width: 100vw
  background-size: cover
  background-repeat: no-repeat
  background-position: bottom
.bottom_ways
  display: flex
.way1
  background: red
  margin-bottom: 3px
.way2
  background: green
  margin-top: 3px
  margin-right: 3px
.way3
  background: blue
  margin-top: 3px
  margin-left: 3px
.center
  position: absolute
  background: #fff
  width: 200px
  height: 200px
  top: 6px
  bottom: 0
  left: 0
  right: 0
  margin: auto
  animation: pulse 2s infinite, pulse2 2s infinite
.arrow
  position: absolute
  width: 83px
  height: 110px
  top: 0
  bottom: 0
  left: 0
  right: 0
  border-radius: 50%
  margin: auto
  transition: 2s
  /* Здесь */
.way1:hover~.arrow
  background: red
.way2:hover~.arrow
  background: green
.way3:hover~.arrow
  background: blue
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/vfj5c6t7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В css вы обращаетесь от верхних элементов к нижнем. ~ позволяет обратиться к соседним элементам.

В вашем случае нижние блоки вложены в контейнер `<div class="bottom_ways">`

Следовательно через `~` вы можете обратиться только к элементам внутри `<div class="bottom_ways">`

В вашем же случае `.arrow` на уровень выше. Поэтому `:hover` работает для красного (который в одном контейнере с `.arrow`) и не работает с другими двумя т.к. они уровнем ниже.

Сделайте так, чтобы все 3 блока были на одном уровне с элементом, которому меняете бэкграунд.

Comment: Спасибо. Других вариантов как я понял нет, только js?

Comment: @Бармалей Да, все верно. Либо править структуру html, либо js